# CertificateException when connecting to Solace

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, certificate, amazon-ecs, solace

I have a java application **'A'** running in an AWS ECS Cluster that connects to a **Solace** message broker instance running on its own ec2 instance in AWS.

Its been working for the last few months but have noticed today the following exception:

> INFO  TcpClientChannel:2377 - Connection attempt
> failed to host 'my-solace-domain-name' ConnectException com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPTransportException: CertificateException - java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: subject/issuer name chaining check failed cause: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: subject/issuer name chaining check failed ((Client name: 139bcb21421e/1/#000f0001   Local addr: <app A's local address:App A's port>   Remote addr: 'my-solace-domain-name':55443) - )

I'm not too experienced with certificate related issues.  Any clues as to why this exception would occur all of a sudden? and what possible fixes can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the client received a server-certificate from the Solace broker but is unable to trust the server-certificate because it cannot create a chain with the trust anchors configured on the client side. Were there any changes to the local client's trust store, or to the server-certificate on the broker side?